# How to fix "exec format error" in AWS lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I'm writing a little POC and trying to work the best way to organize some lambdas.
A service has 3 lambdas:

1. API
2. Message handler
3. Cron

After deploying to AWS, when I test any of the lambdas, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/cron: exec format error",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

In the logs, I find this:

```
START RequestId: 53a7feac-3a6d-4d18-8909-9c8bf659b727 Version: $LATEST
fork/exec /var/task/cron: exec format error: PathError
null
END RequestId: 53a7feac-3a6d-4d18-8909-9c8bf659b727
```

This is my project structure:

- At the root, I got main.go, go.mod and go.sum (it does nothing but it's my attempt to group the packages together and share some dependencies).
- Then I got a few packages

  - api
  - messagehandler
  - cron
  - shared

Each of these packages (except shared) is called main. See below:
[image: project structure]

Here's how I build the packages:

```bash
GOOS=linux
GOARCH=x86_64
echo "GOOS=$GOOS, GOARCH=$GOARCH"
go build -o out/main ./main.go
go build -o out/api ./api/index.go
go build -o out/messagehandler ./messagehandler/index.go
go build -o out/cron ./cron/index.go
```

The output is what I expected:
[image: output folder]

What I confirmed:

- can run the apps in my bash console.
- the lambda handler matches the file name inside the zip.
- the files are built with environment settings GOOS=linux and GOARCH=x86_64

[image: Lambda handler file]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Export your shell variables (both) like `export GOOS=Linux` Otherwise they do not get passed to the environment of processes that you start in the shell

Answer (score 0):

Is your OS Windows?

If so, it is suggested to use the following tool `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/cmd/build-lambda-zip` to prepare the binary to deploy to AWS Lambda.

in `cmd.exe:`

```
set GOOS=linux
set GOARCH=amd64
set CGO_ENABLED=0
go build -o bootstrap main.go
%USERPROFILE%\Go\bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o lambda-handler.zip bootstrap
```

or in `Powershell`:

```
$env:GOOS = "linux"
$env:GOARCH = "amd64"
$env:CGO_ENABLED = "0"
go build -o bootstrap main.go
~\Go\Bin\build-lambda-zip.exe -o lambda-handler.zip bootstrap
```

More details here: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's windows. I'm using the `build-lambda-zip` tool to zip without permission issues. I'm using a shell script because I'll use it in the pipeline. The only difference that I see here compared to my script is the `GCO_ENABLED=0` environment variable but I didn't set it because I didn't want to lock myself out of using a C library (assuming this setting would help me). You think not having this setting could be the culprit? I'll try it later.

Comment: Yes it could be